# nested id's counting for genealoy

Tags: mysql

supose i had logged in by id 47 and there are four id's 55,66,89,91 which have sponsered by 47 that means above four id's are direct achievers of id 47. we can find direct achievers easely but when i try to find all achieves of every direct achievers id and all achievers of that directed ids(nested) and so on... until last id doesn't have any id it's work for me for only 3000 id's. for more than 3000 id's it shows error which is server time out... what should i do[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48636940/search-genealogyachievers-for-mlm-software)

function which developed by me:

supose i had logged in by id 47 and there are four id's 55,66,89,91 which have sponsered by 47 that means above four id's are direct achievers of id 47. we can find direct achievers easely but when i try to find all achieves of every direct achievers id and all achievers of that directed ids(nested) and so on... until last id doesn't have any id it's work for me for only 3000 id's. for more than 3000 id's it shows error which is server time out... what should i do[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48636940/search-genealogyachievers-for-mlm-software)

```
function countachiverfetchCategoryTreeList($parent = '', $user_tree_array = '') {

    if (!is_array($user_tree_array))  $user_tree_array = array();
    $sql = "SELECT `id`,`user_type` FROM `users` WHERE `status` = 1 AND `sponser_id` = $parent   ORDER BY id ASC ";
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    if ($query->num_rows() > 0) {

        foreach ($query->result() as $key) {
            /*  $sef_intro = $this->getselfintroducer($key->id);*/
            $user_tree_array[] = array('id'=>$key->id);
            $user_tree_array = $this->countachiverfetchCategoryTreeList($key->id, $user_tree_array);
        }
    }
    return $user_tree_array;
}
```

Comment: As you have found, this "adjacency-list" model for representing hierarchical data requires recursion to query arbitrary depths. MySQL prior to version 8.0 offers no support for recursive queries and therefore the best option was to remodel the data to use either the "nested sets" or "transitive closure" representations instead—under which hierarchical data can be queried and manipulated to arbitrary depths. MySQL v8.0 has however introduced [recursive CTEs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/with.html#common-table-expressions-recursive) that can solve this problem without remodelling.

Comment: To avoid processing issue, use an algorithm for deep recursive tree (don't lean on `parent_id` only), an approach such as **Nested Set Model** which is very amazing (need to add extra columns `rgt` & `lft`), please [take a look on this](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)

Comment: @eggyat thanks sir, 
but how can use it in codeigniter. if i use mysql 8.0 or greater version???

Comment: @4givN thanks sir 4 your response but what are rgt and lft column values? i don't get it...
means from where it comes?

Comment: What's the point of calling someone "sir" in a conversation in a help forum?